# React date picker returns invalid date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

In google chrome everything works ok. When I open the application in mozilla React Date Picker returns `invalid date`

I tried to use the `moment(this.state.startDate).toDate()`

`new Date(this.state.startDate)` but it doesn't work

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    startDate: new Date()
  };

  handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is error in console?

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati Error: 'Invalid date'

Comment: what is the version of react-datepicker do you use? and what is the version of Mozilla?

Comment: What is `date`?  If it is an event, use `startDate: event.target.value`

Comment: @DenysKozak     "react-datepicker": "^2.6.0", firefox quantum 68.0.2(64 bity) mozilla firefox dla ubuntu

Comment: @Umbro Can you try `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}` instead of `onChange={this.handleChange}`, also what is your react version?

Comment: @Bartosz date is object

Comment: @Umbro could you paste here whole date object?

Comment: @Bartosz Tue Sep 03 2019 12:31:26 GMT+0200 (time)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding dateFormat property like:

```
      <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        dateFormat="d MMM yyyy"
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this approach this code is working perfectly in my project in Mozilla, chrome, and edge. My date picker version is  `"react-datepicker": "^2.7.0",`  and react version is `"react": "^16.8.6",`

```
filters:{
                    startDate: new Date(),
                    endDate: new Date(),
                    type: props.location.state === undefined ? 0 : props.location.state.reportType,
                    reportName : 'Not Selected',
                    reportPreviewCount: 0,
                    reportedUserId: -1,
                    userType: '0',
                },    


    handleChangeDate(date, dateType) {
            let oldState = this.state.filters;

            if(dateType === 'startDate'){
                oldState['startDate'] = date;
                oldState['reportPreviewCount'] = 0;

            }else{
                oldState['endDate'] = date;
                oldState['reportPreviewCount'] = 0;
            }
            this.setState({titleDatatable: [], dataSetDataable: [], filters: oldState, flashState: true});
        }     


                          <DatePicker
                                selected= {props.filters.startDate}
                                onChange={(date) => props.handleChangeDate(date, 'startDate')}
                                className="form-control"
                                peekNextMonth
                                showMonthDropdown
                                showYearDropdown
                                dropdownMode="select"
                                onChangeRaw={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                                withPortal
                            />
```

Comment: Error: 'Invalid time'

Comment: try initiating with the moment.  liek  startDate: moment(),endDate: moment().what are your versions for react and datetime-picker

Comment: in  "react": "^16.6.3" and     "react-datepicker": "1.6.0", i used moment